# date based sorting in ng-table-dynamic

Tags: angularjs, sorting, ngtable

Currently I am using `ng-table-dynamic` table and few of my columns are date (dd/MM/YYYY) formatted. When I try sort those columns, it is sorting based on text format rather than date.

For ex:-  if we have data `14/07/2018,30/05/2018,29/06/2018` then the descending sorting result is `30/05/2018,29/06/2018,14/07/2018` rather than `14/07/2018,29/06/2018,30/05/2018`

```
<table ng-table-dynamic="demo.tableParams with demo.cols" show-filter="true" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
    <td ng-repeat="col in $columns">{{::row[col.field]}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So What is right way to apply sorting based on date format in `ng-table-dynamic`?